# Self Referencing FK - The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, constraints, self-reference

I have a test table **employee** which have self referencing FK **manager_id**:

```
 CREATE TABLE employee (
   employee_id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   employee_name varchar(30), 
   salary varchar(30), 
   manager_id int
);

 ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD CONSTRAINT sr_fk_emp_man 
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
    REFERENCES employee(employee_id)
;

 INSERT INTO employee (employee_name, salary) VALUES 
   ('ISACC NEWTON', 732611),
   ('ROMEO', 329827);

 UPDATE employee SET manager_id = 21 WHERE employee_name = 'ROMEO';
```

Error occurs when I set for PK **employee_id** int IDENTITIY:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "sr_fk_emp_man".
The conflict occurred in database "master", table "dbo.employee", column 'employee_id'.
```

I need to have for PK numeric column that is automatically populated.

I tried to solve a problem with adding sequence instead of IDENTITIY, adding Referential integrity for FK (ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) and set for FK NULL value but nothing changes. I could use **WITH NOCHECK** Constraint but I read that is not the safest option. I am using MS SQL Server.

Comment: In the above script, the two rows will take `IDENTITY` values of `1` and `2`, so why do you use `21`? There is simply no matching row/

Comment: `The conflict occurred in database "master",` PAY ATTENTION to what you are doing. You should not be creating any object any **master** database or using it for general development / learning work.